# How to control the visibility of user's list when we place @user in chatter in salesforce

Tags: community, chatter-feed, userrecordaccess

I want to limit the users which is showing as a list when I place @username on the chatter on the community.

My scenario is that if user place @username in the chatter feed on the community then I want to show that user's list which account is same as current user's account.

Please provide any solution.